# uploading a video to a socket(android)

Tags: java, android, sockets, file-transfer

Good day!I have a problem with transferring video to the client. But the file is being transmitted broken.

Server:

```
 DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(videoFile);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 1024];
    while (fis.read(buffer) != -1) {
        dos.write(buffer);
    }

    fis.close();
    dos.close();
```

Client:

```
   DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
                            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(jsonObject.getString("fileName"));

                            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 1024];
                            int read;
                            int totalRead = 0;
                            int remaining = jsonObject.getInt("fileSize");
                            while ((read = dis.read(buffer, 0, Math.min(buffer.length, remaining))) > 0) {
                                totalRead += read;
                                remaining -= read;
                                System.out.println("read " + totalRead + " bytes.");
                                fos.write(buffer, 0, read);
                            }
                            fos.flush();
                            fos.close();
                            dis.close();
```

I give the name and size in the previous letter.
Where there can be an error?